# How to get selected value of double number range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this range picker for my php project so there is value of selected range between 0 to 100 stored in database.

When page load than i was to set that database value in range picker and after submit button i was to save selected range between 0 to 100 in my database

How i can get & set value of range in rangepicker.

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 400px; margin: 100px auto; padding: 40px;">
  <div id="double_number_range" style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

**js**

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  $("#double_number_range").rangepicker({
    type: "double",
    startValue: 0,
    endValue: 100,
    translateSelectLabel: function(currentPosition, totalPosition) {
      return parseInt(100 * (currentPosition / totalPosition));
    }
  });
}());
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anandp910/4nr63pkL)

Comment: What does not work in your current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there will be better solutions using for example a callback function but you can use the following code too:

```
$("input[type=submit]").on('click', function() {
  var minValue = parseInt($('span.label.select-label:eq(1)').text(), 10);
  var maxValue = parseInt($('span.label.select-label:eq(0)').text(), 10);
  console.log(minValue, maxValue);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw6eu8g7/1/)

Comment: thanx for response, suppose if i have to set value between 0 to 100 than what can i do